# Having trouble understanding php echo logic

Tags: php

PHP newbie here. I'm having trouble undestanding what is going on here.

```
   function doEcho(){
       echo ' Done';
}

echo 'Status ='. doEcho();
```

The above code will return

```
DoneStatus =
```

Why is "Done" coming out before "Status"?

Thank you.

Comment: It's like asking why `$status = $status + 1` works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function, doEcho, doesn't actually return anything - it just prints directly. So what happens is this:

1. Your line `echo 'Status ='. doEcho();` calls the doEcho function in order to combine "Status =" and whatever the doEcho function returns.
2. The doEcho function prints "Done", and then returns nothing.
3. "Status =" is combined with nothing, which is still "Status =", and is then echoed.

That's why the resulting printing is "DoneStatus =". If you want the function to return text to be combined, you need to do `return ' Done';` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the function prints first if you want to output from the function then return. Change the 'echo' within the function to 'return'

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function doEcho(){
   return ' Done';
}
echo 'Status ='. doEcho();
```